# Laravel Guest-checkout is not Working in paypal using "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*" this package also success response is not getting on it

Tags: laravel, paypal, integration, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;

/** All Paypal Details class **/

use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use URL;


class PayPalController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private $_api_context;
    public function __construct()
    {
        /** PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
            $paypal_conf['client_id'],
            $paypal_conf['secret']
        ));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }

    public function getPaymentStatus(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');

            Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
            if (empty($request->input('PayerID')) || empty($request->input('token'))) {
                \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed');
                dd($request->all());
                return Redirect::route('paywithpaypal');
            }
            $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
            $execution = new PaymentExecution();
            $execution->setPayerId($request->input('PayerID'));
            $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);

            if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
                dd("Payment Success");
                \Session::put('success', 'Payment success !!');
                return Redirect::route('paywithpaypal');
            }
           
            \Session::put('error', 'Payment failed !!');
            return Redirect::route('paywithpaypal');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
    }


   
    public function postPaymentWithpaypal(Request $request)
    {
        

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $item_1 = new Item();

        $item_1->setName('Item 1')
            /** item name **/
            ->setCurrency('INR')
            ->setQuantity(1)
            ->setPrice('50');
        /** unit price **/

        $item_list = new ItemList();
        $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('INR')
            ->setTotal('50');

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($item_list)
            ->setDescription('Your transaction description');

        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::to('payment_status'))
            /** Specify return URL **/
            ->setCancelUrl(URL::to('payment_status'));

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
            ->setPayer($payer)
            ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
            ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        
        try {

            $payment->create($this->_api_context);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {

            if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {

                \Session::put('error', 'Connection timeout');
                return Redirect::to('/');
            } else {

                \Session::put('error', 'Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
        }

        foreach ($payment->getLinks() as $link) {

            if ($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {

                $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
                break;
            }
        }

        /** add payment ID to session **/
        Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());

        if (isset($redirect_url)) {

            /** redirect to paypal **/
            return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
        }

        \Session::put('error', 'Unknown error occurred');
        
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

}
```

The above code is to integrate paypal integration plese help me out to solve it
As Code display i have added all the required package used all the class and also added code to integrate but some how because of some issed the paypal scrren is shown at out put but success message is not coming out and i can't work on it

Answer (score 0):

That SDK is deprecated, do not use it.

Using the current SDK, make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server